# how can i read column from csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

```
    a=['Business', 'Food/Clothes', 'Fun', 'Politics', 'Starting_with_Apolog', ['NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['PDT', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['PRP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['UH', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['WP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], 'end__with_ly', 'end_with_al', 'end_with_ful', 'end_with_ible', 'end_with_ic', 'end_with_ive', 'end_with_less', 'end_with_ous', 'sorry_word', 'Gender']

    f = open("file.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = None
    results = []
    for row in reader:
        if not headers:
            headers = []
            for i, col in enumerate(row):
                if col in a:
                    # Store the index of the cols of interest
                    headers.append(i)
            print headers     
        else:
            results.append(list([row[i] for i in headers]))
    return results
```

The above code is to read specific columns in list **a** from **file.csv** so the result will be available in results but the indexing code will only index the following columns:

```
** Fun 63
** Food/Clothes 64
** Politics 70
** Business 73
** end_with_al 75
** end_with_ful 76
** end_with_ible 77
** end_with_ic 78
** end_with_ive 79
** end_with_less 80
** end__with_ly 81
** end_with_ous 82
** sorry_word 83
** Starting_with_Apolog 84
** Gender 1487
```

The code does not index the lists inside the list - how can I make the code search them as well?
Note: file.csv contains some data with 1487 columns; **a** contains some columns from file.csv.

Comment: Are you sure you use the fine separator ?

Comment: What is the significance of the sublists in `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove the list inside the list?

Example

```
'Starting_with_Apolog', ['NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']
```

change to:

```
'Starting_with_Apolog', 'NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'
```

Its a simple hack but it may be the simplest way to go about it.

**EDIT**

Ok so since you want to leave the list within a list structure I believe you are going to have to give up some performance. The next easiest way I can think to solve it is listed below:

```
a=['Business', 'Food/Clothes', 'Fun', 'Politics', 'Starting_with_Apolog', ['NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['NNP', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['PDT', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['PRP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['UH', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], ['WP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP'], 'end__with_ly', 'end_with_al', 'end_with_ful', 'end_with_ible', 'end_with_ic', 'end_with_ive', 'end_with_less', 'end_with_ous', 'sorry_word', 'Gender']
newa = []    
for element in a:
    if isinstance(element, list):
        for el in element:
            newa.append(el)
    else:
        newa.append(element)
a = newa
# Now use "a" or "newa" in the rest of your code.
```

Otherwise your `if col in a:` check is going to get a whole lot more complicated...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `in` doesn't automatically test for inclusion in the sublists in `a`.

```
>>> 'Fun' in a
    True
>>> 'NNP' in a
    False
```

but

```
>>> 'NNP' in a[5] #a[5] is the list ['NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']
    True
```

Comment: @Dylan  i want is as list

Comment: def try_literal_eval(item):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(item)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        return item
a = [try_literal_eval(item=str(item).replace(" ","")) for item in class_label]
print
print a
actually class_label containg the list...so how can i seach using a[i]